# Redirect a user if they do not have a set password before publishing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an interface in my website where a user can create an "unclaimed" order for another user and send them an invitation. The invitation link will be formatted as `/enrollment/orders/:_id`, where `_id` is the id of the order.

One catch is that this can be sent multiple times. On the first time, the user that is invited might not have a password set.

```
Meteor.publish('enrolled_order', function (token) {
  // if user has their password reset, token will also be set for user's account
  return Orders.find({
    'enrollment.token': token
  });
});
```

Here's the catch: During this publication, I want to check certain aspects of the user record and take different actions *instead* of publishing it. For security, I believe this will need to be done on the server to work appropriately.

- if there is no `this.userId`, I want to send them to `login`.
- if the user does not have a password set, I want to redirect them to the reset password page.

Is this possible via a meteor publication?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do this in the router.  If you're using Iron Router, you could use onBeforeAction to check whether the user is logged in:

```
Router.route('/enrollment/orders/:_id', {
  subscriptions: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('enrolled_order', this.params._id);
  },
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if( ! Meteor.userId() ) {
      Router.go( 'loginTemplateName' );
    }
  }
});
```

You aren't going to want to return the hashed password directly to the client, so maybe setting a variable to say whether the password exists or not might be the best approach?

I can't remember if onBeforeAction happens before waitOn, but you might be able to get away with waitOn instead of subscriptions.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would mean that it would be getting published to the client

Comment: Hmm what if you set up an intermediary page that would just check the status of the user and redirect appropriately?  Then you could either redirect to login/etc. or the page where you subscribe?